# Create view in SQL using a parameter from a diff table having a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Getting an error when trying to create a view using a different table for the 'where' part
This is what I tried:

```
Create view vw_OverAllocatedPM as
(
select
firstName, lastName, ssn
from Employee, ProjectDetails
where count(projectManager) > 6
)
```

I also tried:

```
Create view vw_OverAllocatedPM as
(
select
firstName, lastName, ssn
from Employee, ProjectDetails
having count(projectManager) > 6
)
```

The selected columns are from the employee table and the parameter column is FK from a diff table

Any help of info is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: "Any help of info is greatly appreciated" - you should start by posting the error.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I speculate that the query you want looks something like this:

```
select e.firstName, e.lastName, e.ssn
from Employee, ProjectDetails pd join
     Employee e
     on pd.projectManager = e.employeeid  -- no idea what the real join keys are
group by e.firstName, e.lastName, e.ssn
having count(*) > 6;
```

It is rather hard to say what the query really is, because you don't show the table structures nor do you really clearly explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which is perhaps a clue that it is "unclear what you're asking" and so perhaps you should close-vote rather than guess an answer?